# Is there a way to tell maven to test the isolation of a package?

Tags: java, maven, osgi

In one of the projects I'm building for they're using my domain objects jar but only importing one package through OSGi.

Is there a way I can tell maven to check and make sure that none of the classes in this package refer to any other packages and fail the build if so?

Answer (score 0):

You'd be probably looking either for:

- a unit-testing solution like [JUnit4OSGI](https://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-ipojo/apache-felix-ipojo-tools/junit4osgi.html)
- or even one for integration testing, like [Pax-Exam](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/PAXEXAM4)

I've made good experiences with the latter one.